# Is it possible to have try/catch type updates in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

```
UPDATE Table SET Value = 5 WHERE DateTime = '03:42:34';
```

Sometimes that `DateTime` will not exist, though. I'm wondering if there's any way that I can have it dynamically attempt then

```
UPDATE Table SET Value = 5 WHERE DateTime = '03:42:35';
```

This is probably not possible, especially since 'DateTime` is a string, but wondered if there might be some way of doing it.

I had thought of taking the first 7 characters of the `DateTime` and having that match, but that's probably not quite precise enough.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here?  Is DateTime really a varchar of just time?

Comment: no it has the date as well just was omitting the date for speed of typing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working in a straightforward way I feel silly for not thinking of originally:

`UPDATE Table SET Value = 5 WHERE DateTime BETWEEN datetime('2020-03-21 03:42:35', '-1 second') and datetime('2020-03-21 03:42:35', '+1 second')`

Comment: Note that this query will update ALL rows with DateTime in the (1-second) timeframe, even if they are more than 1 rows, even if there are 1000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

The CASE expression sounds like it could do what you want.

> A CASE expression serves a role
>   similar to IF-THEN-ELSE in other
>   programming languages.
>
> The optional expression that occurs in
>   between the CASE keyword and the first
>   WHEN keyword is called the "base"
>   expression. There are two basic forms
>   of the CASE expression: those with a
>   base expression and those without.
>
> In a CASE without a base expression,
>   each WHEN expression is evaluated and
>   the result treated as a boolean,
>   starting with the leftmost and
>   continuing to the right. The result of
>   the CASE expression is the evaluation
>   of the THEN expression that
>   corresponds to the first WHEN
>   expression that evaluates to true. Or,
>   if none of the WHEN expressions
>   evaluate to true, the result of
>   evaluating the ELSE expression, if
>   any. If there is no ELSE expression
>   and none of the WHEN expressions are
>   true, then the overall result is NULL.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
UPDATE Table
SET Value = 5 
WHERE DateTime =
       ( SELECT MIN(DateTime)
         FROM Table
         WHERE DateTime >= '03:42:34'
       )
;
```